# Need libxcb-keysyms.so.1

Tags: yum

I'm running Xubuntu and trying to run the latest Kdenlive appimage. The terminal says I need  libxcb-keysyms.so.1 except I'm getting no help from yum:

```
brett@brett-HP-Laptop-17-bs0xx:~/Bureau$ yum provides libxcb-keysyms.so.1
No Matches found
```

What's the correct package name so I can install this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using `yum` instead of the native `apt-` tools, however on my 16.04 system:

```
$ apt-file search libxcb-keysyms.so.1
libxcb-keysyms1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1
libxcb-keysyms1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1.0.0
```